# Междометие или частица

Tags: междометие

-Ты будешь яблоко?

-Ну () давай.

В данном случае "ну" является междометием или частицей. Как отличить эти части речи друг от друга?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что пишет **Грамма.ру**

Вопрос о разграничении "ну"-частицы и "ну"-междометия не вполне понятен. Справочники обычно указывают на наиболее ясные случаи и обходят стороной ситуации, когда в одинаковом контексте "ну" может быть употреблено и как частица, и как междометие. Ваш вопрос можно свести к следующей проблеме: может ли "ну" в сочетании с личной формой глагола использоваться в обеих функциях (частицы и междометия).

> В справочной литературе ответ на этот вопрос отсутствует. Обращение к Национальному корпусу русского языка показывает, что в большинстве случаев редакторы и корректоры предпочитают определять "ну" в позиции перед личной формой глагола как междометие и отделять ее запятой от глагола:

**Ну, разойдутся через год, ну и бог с ними". [Юрий Трифонов. Дом на набережной (1976)];**

**Овца легла на землю, задерганная верёвкой. ― Ну, посвети. Я отдал фонарь и наклонился над человеком, пластом лежащим на земле. [Юрий Коваль. Гроза над картофельным полем (1974)];**

**Первый раз в жизни. Ну, выпили немного ― разговорились. Заспорили. [Василий Шукшин. Печки-лавочки (1970-1972)];**

**Ну, посиди со мной! ― она силой посадила меня на табуретку. ― Посиди, поговорим о жизни. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Леди Макбет (1970)]**

Однако некоторые редакторы и корректоры считают, что "ну" в этой позиции может использоваться и как усилительная частица, например:
**― Копай яму, ― сказал Булыга и плюнул мимо Шурки. ― Ну выкопаю, ну и что? Шурка прошёлся по поляне вокруг сосны, потыкал лопатой. [Юрий Коваль. У Кривой сосны (1979)] ;**
**Поэтому солдат только пригрозил: «Ну подожди же!» И отошёл от глазка. [Ю. О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 4 (1978)];

**Как только вышли на улицу и отошли на безопасное расстояние, я ему сказал: "Ну начинай. Гитлер входит в бомбоубежище, а там…" [Фазиль Искандер. Летним днем (1969)]**.

Таким образом, "ну" может быть употреблено перед глаголом и как частица, и как междометие, а значит, разграничение этих случаев во  многом опирается на произвол автор (или корректора). При их разграничении учитывается степень связанности "ну" и глагола, наличие самостоятельного ударения у "ну" и паузы между ним и последующим словом.

С уважением

GRAMMA.RU

Answer (score 1):

Дополнение к ответу

Различить частицу и междометие не так уж трудно: учитываем **семантику и наличие паузы**. Значение существенно не меняется (это побуждение к действию), но все зависит **от ситуации.** Переходим от согласия **к требованию)**

― *Ты будешь яблоко?*

― ***Ну** давай.*

― ***Ну,** // давай, где же твое яблоко? Вроде бы обещал.*

Comment: Да, конечно. В примере возможны два варианта. Хотя без дополнительного контекста( которого нет в примере) я выбираю частицу.

Comment: Да, Серж, все верно. В приведенном автором диалоге это именно частица. Спасибо за голос (вам я поставила плюс раньше).

Comment: Спасибо за голос!